# C++ print line not printing to console in Docker container

Tags: c++, docker, docker-for-windows

I've got a very basic proof-of-concept C++ application, shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When this is run locally, it prints `test` to the Console, as expected. However, when run on a Docker container, nothing is printed.

I'm using the `microsoft/windowsservercore` as for my container. Since this is still proof-of-concept, my Dockerfile consists of copying the exe of my C++ into the image, and then I'm manually running it interactively.

Am I missing something that prevents C++ applications from printing to the console inside of a Windows Docker image?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
COPY ./Resources /
```

Resources folder contains only the exe of the C++ application

Docker command: 
`docker run --rm -it proofconcept:latest`, where `proofconcept` is the name given during build

Comment: `using namespace std;` but still uses `std::endl`. Just forgo the `using` and use `std::` where needed. See [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/868546)

Comment: Done. Doesn't fix the problem, but agree that it should be done

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it doesn't fix your issue, but it will save you from many headaches later if you just make this habitual. Also is standard practice in every code shop I've worked in.

Comment: When you say interactively, what is that? I'm not familair with docker, but it sounds like a vm-lite? If I ran this from a terminal/command prompt window, it would show "test" as expected, but If I double clicked the exe, it would just do nothing.

Comment: Instead of starting the exe as part of starting the container, I'm starting the container, attaching to its console, and running the exe from its console. It's roughly equivalent to running straight from console, just inside the container instead of the host

Comment: Ah, so no GUI environment at all, just a command prompt?

Comment: Correct, all command prompt, no GUI even if I wanted one

Comment: How do you compile it, MSVC? Try compiling in /MT mode (static CRT).

Comment: Can you include your Dockerfile and your "docker run" command in the question?

Comment: added now. I was compiling with /MDd in MSVC. Tried switching to /Mt, but getting a large number of linker errors. Working on resolving now

Comment: @rustyx So, /MT gave the same result, but due to a mistype on my part, I found out /MTd mode actually worked! Any idea why the mode change would fix things?

Comment: Apps compiled with MSVC require the VC redistributable package, which installs the necessary DLLs.

Comment: That explains it. If you add an answer, I'll mark as Accepted