# Simple C++ exe std::cout not showing when running within windows container servercore

Tags: c++, docker, windows-container

Some container 101 here please. I can't see messages written to `std::cout` in the console like i would expect, when it's run in a windows server core container. I've tried the same scenario with a C# console app and it outputs unlike the example below. I feel that narrows it down to something on the C++ side of things.

The code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

The Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
ADD Debug/ /
ENTRYPOINT [ "cmd.exe" ]
```

The commands

```
docker build -t cppnet .
docker run -it cppnet
```

The results, first running in the container and second running locally

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting command output in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632959/redirecting-command-output-in-docker)

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks for sharing. Because I'm interactive in the shell, I don't think that's the issue. I've just tried it without the array, so just `ENTRYPOINT cmd.exe` and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect that a C# app will output, whereas a C++ app will not.

Comment: See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580984/c-print-line-not-printing-to-console-in-docker-container#comment86171434_49580984